# Issues with joined table in multiple select for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, multipleselection

I have three models in my application: Customer, Product and Customerproduct. Customerproduct joins Custumer and Product together. Thsu each of the model looks like this:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :customerproducts
  has_many :products, through: :customerproducts
end


class Customerproduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customerproducts
  has_many :customers, through: :customerproducts
end
```

Part of my `customers_controllers.rb` looks like this:

```
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    get_products
  end

  # POST /customers
  # POST /customers.json
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
    get_products

    params[:products][:id].each do |product|
      if !product.blank?
        @customer.customerproducts.build(:product_id => product)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_customer
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :address, :email, :phone_number, :occupation, :field, :country, :customertype_id, :status, :sales_cycle, :sub_id)
    end

    def get_products
      @all_products = Product.all
      @customer_product = @customer.customerproducts.build
    end
```

Whenever I try to create a new customer,a fter selecting the list of products, I get the error `Customerproducts is invalid`. What could I possibly be doing wrong. So far I have tried all solutions I can think of, and nothing worked.
[Customerproducts is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjnJS.png)

This is the views of my form (with some parts not relevant to this question removed).

```
<%= form_for(customer) do |f| %>
  <% if customer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this customer from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% customer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :customertype %>
    <%= f.select(:customertype_id, Customertype.all.map { |p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, { include_blank: 'Select Customer Type'}) %>
  </div>

  <%= fields_for(@customer_product) do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label "Select Products" %>
      <%= collection_select(:products, :id, @all_products, :id, :name, { include_blank: false, include_hidden: false }, { multiple: true }) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :sub %>
    <%= f.select(:sub_id, Sub.all.map { |p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, { include_blank: 'Select SUB'}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Server log

```
Started GET "/customers/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-04 23:48:51 +0100
Processing by CustomersController#new as HTML
  Rendering customers/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Customertype Load (145.3ms)  SELECT "customertypes".* FROM "customertypes"
  Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  Sub Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "subs".* FROM "subs"
  Rendered customers/_form.html.erb (339.8ms)
  Rendered customers/new.html.erb within layouts/application (487.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1746ms (Views: 1414.8ms | ActiveRecord: 148.0ms)


Started POST "/customers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-04 23:49:22 +0100
Processing by CustomersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OKDBbqi24/ZNxcfhYwRghwfpCh/XHFYjxGbq8XPxRmSzc+uB7XrrfG9RkiZ/8FTbHZfnaRlK3SCvIG88/nfbVg==", "customer"=>{"customertype_id"=>"1", "name"=>"lord henry", "address"=>"9 Olusegun Street", "country"=>"NG", "email"=>"me@gmail.com", "phone_number"=>"08122334455", "occupation"=>"Engineer", "field"=>"Civil", "sub_id"=>"2"}, "products"=>{"id"=>["1", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Create Customer"}
  (275.6ms)  BEGIN
  Customertype Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "customertypes".* FROM "customertypes" WHERE "customertypes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Sub Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "subs".* FROM "subs" WHERE "subs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering customers/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Customertype Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "customertypes".* FROM "customertypes"
  Product Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  Sub Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "subs".* FROM "subs"
  Rendered customers/_form.html.erb (313.0ms)
  Rendered customers/new.html.erb within layouts/application (322.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1351ms (Views: 873.4ms | ActiveRecord: 299.0ms)
```

Comment: Please post a full error message

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I have included an image to the error message. It just shows `Customerproducts is invalid`.

Comment: could you also post the server logs please

Comment: @AmrElBakry done that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller filename should be `customers_controller.rb`not `customer_controllers.rb` and inside it `CustomersController < ApplicationController` to follow Rails conventions.

Also, in your `customer` form, you're using a local variable instead of the instance variable passed from the controller. Change `customer` to `@customer` in your form.